# React with redux - react-rating with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement a simple form, where user can rate a post while posting a comment. I found `react-rating` on github and wanted to use it in my `redux-form`.

I place my `StarRating` component

```
<StarRating onChange={(value) => { this.changeRate("rating", value) } }/>
```

and hidden `Field` inside my form with name set to `"rating"`

```
<Field component="input" type="hidden" name="rating"/>
```

Function called `changeRate` is meant to change the value of the hidden field inside my form to the value after clickinf on the stars.

```
changeRate(name, value) {
    this.props.change(name, value) // function provided by redux-form
}
```

When I click for the first time on the rating the value of the inpute changes, but the selected stars disappears. After clicking for the second time the stars stay selected.

I tried to change the value of the hidden field using jQuery. - selecting the stars worked properly but the field value was not included inside the redux-form when posting. Combining jQuery and `change` function gives the same result as with no jQuery.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you will need some `dynamic props` to represent the number of stars that is changing in your starRating component, and not only the onChange callback like you did. Something like that:

```
<StarRating 
  onChange={(value) => { this.changeRate("name", value) } }
  initialRate={ this.state.starRating }
/>
```

You will need to adapt your function to also change the local state that represent the stars numbers. Something like that:

```
changeRate(name, value) {
    this.props.change(name, value) // function provided by redux-form
    this.setState({ starRating: value })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to write this but isn't it better to do a custom component and reuse it wherever you like instead of hiding the Field component each time? You can use either react-stars or react-rating.

RenderRatingField.js

```
//custom Component
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactStars from "react-stars";

export class RenderRatingField extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      label,
      name,
      topTxt,
      starCount,
      input: { value, onChange },
      starSize,
      starsColor,
      meta: { touched, error }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <label>
              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <h1>{topTxt}</h1>
                <ReactStars
                  count={starCount}
                  value={value === "" ? this.props.initialStars : value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  size={starSize}
                  color2={starsColor}
                />
              </div>
              {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MainComponent.js

```
//usage
 <Field
  name="myStars"
  initialStars={0}
  starCount={5}
  type="number"
  starSize={24}
  topTxt={'My Stars'} 
  starsColor={"#f00"}
  component={RenderRatingField} />
```